# R: create a new column from an existing one

Tags: r

I have the following column

```
col1 <- c("J-FG12", "M-L2", "F-001","J-82")
```

I want to create a second column that considers everything before the `"-"`

```
col2 <- c("J","M","F","J")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(col2 = sub("([^-]+).*", "\\1", col1))
    col1 col2
1 J-FG12    J
2   M-L2    M
3  F-001    F
4   J-82    J
```

Here we are using a negative character class `[^-]+`, matching one or more times, which allows any character but the dash/minus `-`, thus effectively capturing whatever comes before the `-`, and refer to it in `sub`'s replacement clause via backreference `\\1`

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("J-FG12", "M-L2", "F-001", "J-82"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `trimws`

```
trimws(col1, whitespace = "-.*")
[1] "J" "M" "F" "J"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stringr::word` function: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/word.html.

```
word(col1, sep = "-")
```

Comment: Shouldn't you put: `df$col2 <- word(df$col1, sep = "-")`?

Comment: Yes, but this solution also works inside a `mutate` context.

Answer (score 1):

We can use stringr with `str_extract` and a lookahead(`(?=)`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(col2 = str_extract_all(col1, '^.+?(?=-)'))

    col1 col2
1 J-FG12    J
2   M-L2    M
3  F-001    F
4   J-82    J
```

Comment: what if there's a string such as `J-F-G12`? Then your result will be `J-F`

Comment: Thanks for your imput. I added a non-greedy quantifier and it is now OK, even with your example

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(col1 = c("J-FG12", "M-L2", "F-001", "J-82"))

df %>%
  mutate(col2 = str_extract(col1, "^.*-") %>%
    str_remove("-"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   col1   col2 
#>   <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 J-FG12 J    
#> 2 M-L2   M    
#> 3 F-001  F    
#> 4 J-82   J


#using tidyr

df %>% 
  separate(col1,
           c('col2','col1'),
           '-')
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   col2  col1 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 J     FG12 
#> 2 M     L2   
#> 3 F     001  
#> 4 J     82


#if the characters preceding `-` are all upper case
df %>%
  mutate(col2 = str_extract(col1, "[:UPPER:]+"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   col1   col2 
#>   <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 J-FG12 J    
#> 2 M-L2   M    
#> 3 F-001  F    
#> 4 J-82   J

#another approach using str_split and selecting the first element of the resulting lists

df$col1 %>% 
  str_split('-') %>% 
  map_chr(~.[[1]])
#> [1] "J" "M" "F" "J"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>